# Primeflex Grid System adds unwanted margin

Tags: html, css, angular, primeflex

When using Primeflex 3.3.1 in Angular it automatically adds margin on the right and always adds a horizontal scrollbar. Here some minimal example:

```html
<div>
  <h2>Chargepoint Simulator</h2>
</div>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="col">
    TEST
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Here you can see the margin on the righ]

How can I prevent this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I increase the gap of a PrimeFlex grid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75482687/how-can-i-increase-the-gap-of-a-primeflex-grid)

Comment: The duplicate can also be used to reduce the gutter.

Comment: @JasperdeVries Did you read my question? As soon as I add a column to my grid, the whole grid has a margin on the right and the grid gets bigger than my page width, so a scrollbar gets added. I just want a normal grid behavior. I don't want to change something regarding gap

Comment: When using `.my-gutter [class*=col] { padding: 0; }` as in the other post suggested, nothing happens